# HTML Drag and Drop API -

Tags: javascript, html, api, drag-and-drop

This is a simple math game.

My problem: I cannot drag the images in the middle and drag them to the left side. I did some research on the internet but could not find any results.

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleSheet.css" />
  <script src="myScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--İŞLEMLER-->
  <div id="islemler">
    <!--1.İŞLEM-->
    <div>
      <img src="images/question-mark.png" ondrop="dropHandler(event)" ondragover="dragoverHandler(event)">
      <img src="images/plus.png">
      <img src="images/question-mark.png" ondrop="dropHandler(event)" ondragover="dragoverHandler(event)">
      <img src="images/equal.png">
      <img src="images/eight.png">
    </div>


  </div>
  <!--TAŞINACAK RAKAMLAR-->
  <div id="tasinacakRakamlar">
    <img src="images/three.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstartHandler(event)">
    <img src="images/five.png" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragstartHandler(event)">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

**JS:**

```
function dragstartHandler(e){
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text",e.target.id);
}

function dragoverHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //e.dataTransfer.dropEffect="copy";
}

function dropHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var myData = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(myData));
}
```

Comment: whats your question? what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: I want to drag the images of tasinacakrakamlar (images/three.png and five.png) onto the question marks.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Other users marked your question for low quality and need for improvement. I re-worded/formatted your input to make it easier to read/understand. Please review my changes to ensure they reflect your intentions. But I think your question is still not answerable. **You** should [edit] your question now, to add missing details (see [mcve] ). Feel free to drop me a comment in case you have further questions or feedback for me.

Answer (score 0):

Well, your trying to getElementByID but your elements dosent have ID.
put ID on your elements.

```js
function dragstartHandler(e){
    e.dataTransfer.setData("text",e.target.id);
}

function dragoverHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    //e.dataTransfer.dropEffect="copy";
}

function dropHandler(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var myData = e.dataTransfer.getData("text");
    e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(myData));
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styleSheet.css" />
  <script src="myScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!--İŞLEMLER-->
  <div id="islemler">
    <!--1.İŞLEM-->
    <div>
      <img src="images/question-mark.png" ondrop="dropHandler(event)" ondragover="dragoverHandler(event)">
      <img src="images/plus.png">
      <img src="images/question-mark.png" ondrop="dropHandler(event)" ondragover="dragoverHandler(event)">
      <img src="images/equal.png">
      <img src="images/eight.png">
    </div>


  </div>
  <!--TAŞINACAK RAKAMLAR-->
  <div id="tasinacakRakamlar">
    <img src="images/three.png" draggable="true" id="ele1" ondragstart="dragstartHandler(event)">
    <img src="images/five.png" draggable="true" id="ele2" ondragstart="dragstartHandler(event)">
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```